Remove duplicates from a list of tuples that involve matrices
I am trying to remove the duplicates from a list of tuples that contains matrices. The tuples are composed of two items: a number and a corresponding matrix.  To be considered a ‘duplicate’, both the number and the matrix must be identical to another tuple in the list.
For instance, a shortened version of my initial list is as follows (notice the last two tuples are identical, and thus the goal is to remove one of them):
[  ( 5.42,
      c1     c2    c3     c4     
r1    1      1      1      1    
r2    1      0      0      0   
r3    0      1      0      1     
r4    0      0      0      0 ),

  ( 4.31,
      c1    c2     c3     c4     
r1    0     1      0      1    
r2    0     1      1      1    
r3    0     0      0      0   
r4    1     0      0      1 ),

  ( 5.42,
      c1     c2    c3    c4     
r1    0      0      0     0    
r2    0      0      1     0     
r3    0      0      0     1   
r4    1      1      1     1 ),

  ( 5.42,
      c1    c2    c3    c4     
r1    0     0      0     0    
r2    0     0      1     0     
r3    0     0      0     1   
r4    1     1      1     1 )  ]

The desired output will be a list of 3 tuples (instead of the initial 4), all tuples now being unique
[  ( 5.42,
      c1    c2    c3    c4     
r1    1     1     1     1    
r2    1     0     0     0   
r3    0     1     0     1     
r4    0     0     0     0),

  ( 4.31,
      c1    c2    c3    c4     
r1    0     1     0     1    
r2    0     1     1     1    
r3    0     0     0     0   
r4    1     0     0     1 ),

  ( 5.42,
      c1    c2    c3    c4     
r1    0     0     0     0    
r2    0     0     1     0     
r3    0     0     0     1   
r4    1     1     1     1 )  ]

All of my attempts result in either one of two errors:
ValueError:  The truth value of the DataFrame is ambiguous.  Use a.empty() , a.bool(), a.item() or a.all()
-or-
TypeError:  DataFrame objects are mutable, thus cannot be hashed
When I check the ‘type’ of my incoming tuple-list, it returns <Class ‘list’>.  So, I am confused that my error messages reference DataFrames.
Just a sample of my many attempts include:
(Note, the incoming list is ‘tup_list' below)
attempt example 1:
from itertools import groupby
deduped = [next (g) for k, g in groupby (sorted (tup_list), key = lambda tup: tup [:2] ) ]
attempt example 2:
new_tup_list = [ tuple (item) for item in tup_list ]
deduped = list (set (new_tup_list) )
attempt example 3:
deduped = list (set (map(tuple, tup_list) ) )
 attempt example 4:
from collections import OrderedDict
`for t in tup_list:
d.setdefault ( t[1], t )
deduped = list( d.values() )
attempt example 5:
deduped = set()
temp = [deduped.add((a,b))  for (a,b) in tup_list if (a,b) not in deduped]
If you have any advice as to how to successfully remove duplicates from a list of tuples that involves matrices, I would be most appreciative – Thank you.

You can convert the dataframe to string and use that to remove duplicates, e.g. (if lst contains your tuples):
tmp = {}
for v, df in lst:
    tmp[(v, str(df))] = (v, df)

print(list(tmp.values()))

Prints:
[(5.42,     c1  c2  c3  c4
r1   1   1   1   1
r2   1   0   0   0
r3   0   1   0   1
r4   0   0   0   0), (4.31,     c1  c2  c3  c4
r1   0   1   0   1
r2   0   1   1   1
r3   0   0   0   0
r4   1   0   0   1), (5.42,     c1  c2  c3  c4
r1   0   0   0   0
r2   0   0   1   0
r3   0   0   0   1
r4   1   1   1   1)]


So, I guess I have list of tuples - made up of a number and a dataframe.  Okay, I think I am understanding better.  So, the idea is to just turn the matrices into strings.  I will try -- thank you! :)
